# Insert small table into large table, keep track of IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `small`, that contains three columns: `(id, first_name, last_name)`.  I have a much larger table named `large`, that also contains three columns: `(id, first_name, last_name)`. Both `id` columns are auto_increment. I would like to insert every row from `small` into `large`, but I'd also like to keep track of how the ID numbers change.  That is, I want to create an auxilary table with the structure `(small_id, large_id)`.

Is there a clean way to do this? I don't want to modify the schema of either table. I also can't do a join after inserting, since there is no guarantee `(first_name, last_name)` is unique. I'm not even sure how to cleanly and correctly get the new ID numbers that these inserted rows get in `large`.  Currently what I have is:

```
INSERT INTO large (first_name, last_name) SELECT first_name, last_name FROM small;
SET @cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM small);
SELECT id FROM large ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT @cnt;
```

But that just seems error-prone.

(If there is another way to do this without creating another table, I'm open to that as well.)

Comment: why not modify the large table to contain id, first, last, small_id and then insert the small table with id as small_id?  will that give you what you're looking for?

Comment: @DCR: I cannot modify either table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do it only once and uninterrupted, then you may set large.id auto increment seed to number larger than any other large.id:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000001;
```

Then you run your script to insert records from small to large:

```
INSERT INTO large (first_name, last_name)
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name FROM small s ORDER BY s.id;
```

Then set large.id auto increment seed to number large than any other large.id again:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 2000001;
```

Now you have range [1000001, 2000000] reserved for values from table small.
Conversion from small.id to large.id is very simple:

```
large.id = small.id + 1000000
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was inserting all of those rows, there aren't any going to be rejected because of duplicates, or whatever.

The approach I would use would be to add an offset value to the `id` from the `small`. Assuming that `id` values in `small` are all positive, I would just use the maximum value of `id` from `large` as the offset.  For example, if the maximum `id` value in `large` is `142014`

```
 INSERT INTO large (id, ... )
 SELECT id + 42014 AS new_id, ... FROM small ;
```

If I wanted to record that "mapping", and I can't modify either `small` or `large`, I'd create another table to hold the two values:

```
 SELECT id AS old_id, id + 42014 AS new_id FROM small
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out in comments, you should change the table structure of the `large` table to include the `small.id` column value and just `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM small` directly.

If this cannot be done for some reason, you need to create a script to transfer the records (pseudocode):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS large_small(small_id INT UNSIGNED, large_id INT UNSIGNED);

SELECT MAX(small_id) AS max_small_id FROM large_small;
rows = SELECT * FROM small WHERE id > :max_small_id;
foreach row in rows:
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO large(first_name, last_name) VALUES(row.first_name, row.last_name);
    INSERT INTO large_small(small_id, large_id) VALUES(row.id, LAST_INSERT_ID());
    COMMIT;
```